# Binding in the WPF DataGridColumn HeaderStyle

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm applying the following style to my DataGridColumns (via their `HeaderStyle` property):

```
    <Style x:Key="MyHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="???" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The same style is applied to each column but I need some way of altering the content (such as the TextBlock text) depending on which column it is. I believe the DataGridColumnHeader has no binding of its own, so how could I achieve this? The number of columns will vary, so I can't simply create a separate style for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TemplateBinding - it allows you to reach out of your ControlTemplate to get information about the actual control using this control template.  My sample will bind the textblock to the content that's declared in the normal way for a DataGridColumHeader.

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That helps thanks. Ultimately I want to include a button in the header template, but I need to bind its CommandParameter to something that can identify which column's button was clicked. So, is there any way to bind to properties of the corresponding DataGridColumn (e.g. DisplayIndex)? Alternatively, when I'm creating my DataGridColumns (which I'm doing programmatically), is there any way to get at the column's corresponding DataGridColumnHeader, so I can set a property such as Tag (which I can then bind CommandParameter to)?

Comment: Never mind, I've found a solution. I realised the Header property is of type object, so I can utilise this. In the above control template I then do something like '<TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}" Text="{Binding FooProperty}" />'. Likewise for my button's CommandParameter - I can bind it to some kind of ID or other column identifier in the Header object.